# Python webcam live edit on MS Teams

Tags: python, opencv

Say if I am in a meeting on Microsoft Teams with my web camera ON, is it possible to live edit the webcam input in Python and then show it as an output to the other meeting members as my webcam video? Is it possible to do this in OpenCV?

I know that the webcam video can be edited with OpenCV, but how do I show the edit as my webcam output live on the MS Teams meeting?

Thank you.

Comment: yes. install the output as a camera device on your OS.

Comment: how do I install the output as a camera device?? I have windows 10.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/681386/webcam-driver-that-uses-an-image-or-video-file-as-the-video-source

Comment: https://altercam.com/articles/broadcast-video-file.html

Comment: The thing to google for seems to be "virtual webcam" or "virtual camera driver"

Comment: Are you able to suggest how to do this in Python, without installing any software?

Comment: Just cos of curiosity, why u not using screen view?

Comment: because there would be multiple people in the session, with their webcam turned on.